# 1st law of thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, gravity

If gravity fields create pressure at their center which creates thermal energy, then isn't a gravity field creating energy that otherwise wouldn't be there (breaking the first law of thermodynamics).

Comment: I cannot understand your question! Could you please explain _everything_?

Comment: The gravitational potential energy is decreasing so the internal energy is increasing, consistent with the 1st law of thermodynamics.

Comment: But theoretically couldn’t you move enough mass together to create a planet with little energy used in the first place since there is zero friction in space.

Comment: So.....As I said, gravitational potential energy got converted to internal energy.  Are you saying that, because no external work was done and no heat was transferred that the internal energy change should be $\Delta U =0$?